# jq parsing and linux formatting to desired output

Tags: linux, jq

I am trying to format json output and exclude an element when a condition is met.

1) In this case I'd like to exclude any element that contains "valueFrom" using jq

```
[{
        "name": "var1",
        "value": "var1value"
    },
    {
        "name": "var2",
        "value": "var2value"
    },
    {
        "name": "var3",
        "value": "var3value"
    },
    {
        "name": "var4",
        "value": "var4value"
    },
    { # <<< exclude this element as valueFrom exists
        "name": "var5",  
        "valueFrom": {
            "secretKeyRef": {
                "key": "var5",
                "name": "var5value"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

After excluding the element mentioned above I am trying to return a result set that looks like this.

```
var1: var1value
var2: var2value
var3: var3value
var4: var4value
```

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By *"feedback is appreciated"*, do you mean *"please give me the code"*? Are there any reasons you made no effort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select array items that doesn't have the `valueFrom` key using a combination of [`select/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)), [`has/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#has(key)), and [`not/0`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#and/or/not). Then format the objects as you please.

```
$ jq -r '.[] | select(has("valueFrom") | not) | "\(.name): \(.value)"' input.json
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated.